# How can I fix a PDF document that was scanned backwards?

Tags: pdf, document

I received an email containing a PDF document which was scanned backwards. I tried rotating it with PDF Complete version 4.0.65 but it didn't correct the problem. The user who emailed it doesn't have the original document to re-scan it correctly. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you only looking for existing tools or would you also do some coding? In the latter case there are many PDF manipulation libraries out there allowing you to achieve your goal.

Comment: I was hoping PDF Complete could do it, but have to resort to an existing tool like BullZip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for all pdf's

- Install a pdf printer like bullzip pdf printer
  http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php
- open the pdf in eg. Adobe Reader and select print,
- Select the pdf printer as the printer
- in the "pages to print area" select more options and select reverse
  pages.

This will create a pdf with the pages in reverse order

Comment: Although I have a Cannon MG3200 printer/scanner/copier, which can scan to a PDF file, and PDF Complete software, my objective is to fix the PDF file itself so that I can email it to someone else. But thanks for contributing your answer any way, as it's good info to know for a future need!

Comment: Hi The pdf printer from bullzip is a software printer. It creates a pdf file from whatever you try to print(it could be an image, a word document or it could even be you pdf) and if you select the reverse order, the new pdf file will be created with all pages reversed

Comment: Oh sorry, I just read the webpage. It's similar to like printing to an XPS file. I'll try it and if it works, mark your answer as accepted, thanks!

Comment: Yes it is similar to printing to an XPS file (except it is for a pdf) and i just tried it with a couple of my own pdf's so it should work for you as well

Comment: It solved the problem. It's also a handy tool as well, thank you!

Comment: works also with cups + evince in default Ubuntu install (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04)

Answer (score 29):

If you want a Linux simple solution, pdftk is able to do exactly that:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat end-1 output output.pdf
```

Comment: If you want pdftk for mac and have homebrew installed you can 
brew install https://raw.github.com/quantiverge/homebrew-binary/pdftk/pdftk.rb

Comment: Wow. that was as easy as it gets. Thank you.

Comment: Update for Homebrew:
brew install pdftk-java

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way to do this.

1. Press `Ctrl + P` to bring the print dialog.
2. Choose `Microsoft Print to PDF.` (Not sure if this is available on windows 7 or lower; else choose `Adobe PDF` in the drop-down menu)
3. Press `More Options` and then check `Reverse Pages`.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: good solution, but file size grows up

Comment: I am almost certain this is due to compression, you could check the `Advanced` settings to see if something can help. Since my answer in 2017, there were several improvements and there are now more free virtual printer services on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PDFtk GUI for Windows too.
But this feature needs the Pro license, today (04/15/2017) the price is $3,99.

Link: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-pro/

[image]